# Django Caught Warning while rendering: Incorrect integer value: ... for column 'user_id' at row 1

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-widget

I am building a section for my site that allows **hunters to write hunting reports.**

in this section they can choose from a **'wish list'** (animals they would like to hunt) and **'bag list'** (animals they have hunted)

I have built the form, and need to make use of some filters to extract **only user related data**.

I am having troubles with either my forms.py or something else due to the TemplateSyntaxError.

Basics of what I want is the 'bag list' to filter through **my trophies only**, and the user not having to select himself but to be already passed through, i.e. no select menu for the user.

**my forms.py looks like this**

```
class HuntingReportForm(ModelForm):
    date_travel_started = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1970,2012)))
    date_travel_ended = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1970,2012)))
    wish_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Specie.objects.all(), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False), required=False)
    bag_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Trophies.objects.all(), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = HuntingReport
        #exclude = ['user',]

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        #self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.validate = kwargs.pop('validate', False)
        super(HuntingReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['bag_list'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Trophies.objects.filter(user = user), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False), required=False)
        users = User.objects.filter(userprofile__outfitter=True)
        self.fields['outfitter'].choices = [('', '')] + [(user.pk, user.get_full_name()) for user in users]
        self.fields.keyOrder = ['title', 'date_travel_started', 'date_travel_ended', 'outfitter', 'wish_list', 'bag_list','report', 'user']
```

your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overridden the signature of the form's `__init__` method, by adding the `user` arg first. You'll need to change everywhere you initialise the form to ensure you pass in `user` before `request.POST`.

Or, preferably, go back to the commented-out code you had which takes `user` from the kwargs dict, and remove the reference to `user` in the method signature.

Comment: thanks. Just to make sure I understand the second part, "Or, preferably, go back to the commented-out code you had which takes user from the kwargs dict, and remove the reference to user in the method signature." so remove "user" from def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs): to look as def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) and that should work?

Comment: Yes, as long as you uncomment the `self.user` line as well.